# How to get past the rock wall in Ultrakill?

Tags: ultrakill

In the Prelude Third level (Double Down) there is a rock wall that I cannot pass through.

[image: Large Rock Wall]

When I touch it an 'insufficient firepower' "error" appears on the screen.

**How do I get past this point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Video](https://youtu.be/8uTPWfW6Hlw?t=93) shows the player using a shotgun to blow down the wall.  The right click option for the shotgun should fire an explosive:

> Press 'Right Mouse Button' to fire an explosive.

They appear to have obtained the shotgun just prior to this by taking down the boss in its first phase.

Comment: Completely missed the boss room on this level my first time around. Turns out you can also get the shotgun in a secret encounter on the previous level.

Answer (score 1):

The game will teach you this later, when you get the shotgun (5-10 minutes from this wall, I think? Don't really remember), but essentially: cracked walls can only be blown open by the shotgun's secondary fire (be it the default launcher mod or the pump mod; although you need to punch the bullets when doing this with the pump mod).